# Почему выбивает исключение Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'UnitStateWord' was corrupted?

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

   char m,
        n,
        l,        
        w;
    unsigned __int16 UnitStateWord;
    printf("Введите слово состояния устройства \n");
    printf("(16-ричное число от 0 до 0xFFFF) >");
    scanf_s("%x", &UnitStateWord);

    m = (UnitStateWord >> 13) & 7;
    n = (UnitStateWord >> 10) & 7;
    l = (UnitStateWord >> 8) & 1;
    w = UnitStateWord & 0xFF;

   
    return 0;
     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что

```
unsigned __int16 UnitStateWord;
```

подразумевает 2 байта в `UnitStateWord`, а `"%x"` - четырехбайтовое целое. В результате запись идет в память за пределами переменной и портит стек...

Кстати, VC++ прямо говорит об этом:

> `t.cpp(18): warning C4477: "scanf_s": в строке форматирования "%x" требуется аргумент типа "unsigned int *", но вариативный аргумент "1" имеет тип "unsigned short *"`
> `t.cpp(18): note: рекомендуется использовать "%hx" в строке форматирования`

Чем вы компилировали? или просто не поняли сообщение?

Comment: VC++2019, но там кроме исключения ничего нету

Comment: как тогда правильно записать scanf чтобы она принимала 2 байтное 16-ричное число?

Comment: Посмотрите последнюю строчку в ответе. И включите предупреждения в компиляторе!

Comment: я не понимаю одно, здесь [https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/] пишет, что для %x, h означает  `unsigned short int*`, но длина `unsigned short int*` зависит от компилятора, и она может отличатся

Comment: В используемом вами компиляторе `__int16_t` и есть `short int`. Впрочем, можете воспользоваться `#include<inttypes.h>` и определенной в нем форматной строкой `SCNx16` для `__int16`.